# I am unable to add latex into my blog in sanity.io

Tags: reactjs, next.js, deployment, latex, sanity

I recently started web development using next.js and sanity.io. I want to use latex plug-in of sanity.io but I am not quite sure how to do that. I am sending the link of my github so please if anyone can help me it would be great. [Click here](https://github.com/AfrozSaqlain/my-blogposts)

```
export default {
    name: 'post',
    title: 'Post',
    type: 'document',
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'title',
            title: 'Title',
            type: 'string',
        },
        {
            name: 'overview',
            title: 'Overview',
            type: 'string',
        },
        {
            name: 'slug',
            title: 'Slug',
            type: 'slug',
            options: {
                source: 'title',
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'content',
            title: 'Content',
            type: 'array',
            of: [
                {
                    type: 'block'
                },
                {
                    type: 'image',
                    fields: [
                        {
                            name: 'alt',
                            title: 'Alternative text',
                            type: 'text',
                        },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    name: 'myLatexField',
                    type: 'latex'
                  }
            ],
        },
    ],
}
```

As mentioned, I installed sanity latex plugin using `npm install --save sanity-plugin-latex-input` and in my sanity.config.ts I added

```
import { latexInput } from "sanity-plugin-latex-input";

export default defineConfig({
  /* ... */

  plugins: [
      latexInput()
  ]
})
```

And then in sanity studio I was able to see the latex component but when I wrote there and tried to publish it, then on the webpage that latex isn't getting rendered.